# Cómo resolver el error 401 con API MAILCHIMP y PHP?

Tags: api, php7

Hola estoy tratando de usar la api de mailchimp para poner etiquetas a los usuarios ya registrados, pero me sale un error

> {"type": "
>   http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/
>   ", "title": "API Key Invalid", "status": 401, "detail": "Your la
>   solicitud no incluía una clave API. "," instancia ":" "}

la url a la q mando llamar en el post esta conectado así:

```
$memberID = md5(strtolower($postEmail));
$dataCenter = substr($apiKey,strpos($apiKey,'-')+1);
$url = 'https://' . $dataCenter . '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/' . $audienceID . '/members/' . $memberID.'/tags';
```

Alguien que me pueda ayudar de en que parte estoy metiendo mal la clave api porque pues al final si me esta dando respuesta la api solo pues no lee la apikey

Answer (score 0):

El error que muestra ahí dice claramente `Your la solicitud no incluía una clave API`, necesitas enviarle la clave API con una de los métodos de autenticación que ofrece Mailchimp descritos en el link:

https://mailchimp.com/developer/guides/get-started-with-mailchimp-api-3/#Authentication_methods

Si optas por la autenticación Http básico y si estás usando `curl` en PHP para la conexión, puedes hacer el llamado con la función:

```
curl_setopt($curlObject, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "cualquiercosa:" . $apiKey);
```

Donde `cualquiercosa` es el nombre de usuario que según la documentación de Mailchimp puede ser cualquier texto, sólo importa la API key.

Comment: ah perfecto, se ve mas practico por curl , entiendo que en "cualquiercosa" va el json ? pero que info va en $curlObject y CURLOPT_USERPWD ? perdon algo ando confundido bueno este CURLOPT_USERPWD me imagino es mi contraseña pero encriptada en que md5?

Comment: Si no estabas usando curl, con qué método estabas haciendo el request, quizás sea mejor orientarte de esa forma así no te confundes.

Comment: habia encontrado una maner sin culr puro php por medio de una url y metodo get se llenaba pero veo mejor la opcion de curl ya lo pude lograr